# Is it as expected that Polars has slower performance for simple arithmetic operations than Numpy?

Tags: numpy, python-polars

The task I am benchmarking with is simply **clipping values element-wise**. I have done this using both `numpy` and `polars`. But, it turned out that using `numpy` is much faster (~5x) than using `polars` (as shown below).

So, my question:

- Is this behavior as expected?
- If so, does it mean that `polars` (although it is highly optimized for join/groupby), may not be well-suited for performing relatively simple numerical vector/array operations such as clipping in my example?

```py
import timeit
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

N = 10_000_000
x = np.random.normal(size=N)
y = np.random.normal(size=N)
z = y + 0.5
df = pl.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "z": z})

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: np.minimum(np.maximum(x, y), z), number=10)
0.60923

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: df.select(pl.min(pl.max(pl.col("x"), pl.col("y")), pl.col("z"))), number=10)
3.39337
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update 25th April 2023

As of `polars >= 0.17.8` we optimized it a bit more. It is much closer now.

Our horizontal `min` operation is not really optimized. If you open an issue we can improve that. Most of our optimization attention has gone to the expensive operations.

### it depends

To answer your question, no it depends.

- Polars can achieve the same numeric performance for columnar operations.
- It will be slower for row-wise operations and operations that utilize
  blas, like dot products.

In aggregate, polars might be faster; as often, many operations are able to run in parallel. If you feel it is too slow in one area, open an issue.